# Secure Cookies not working with hostname set in hosts file

Tags: cookies, session-cookies, gorilla, httpcookie

I have cookies set as secure, but it's working as localhost. But with the domain name set in the hosts file, chrome is not sending the cookies to server resulted in request failing.
i am running my server on the localhost with the following cookie set, the cookie is being sent by chrome to my server.

```
cookie := http.Cookie{Name: "XSRF-TOKEN", Value: csrf.Token(r), Expires: expiration, Path: "/", HttpOnly: false, Secure: true}
```

I have set the following in my host file and trying to open from chrome x.test.in the cookie is not getting passed . chrome reporting as `set-cookie was blocked because it has the secure attribute but was not received` the following code is in golang and using gorilla mux

```
127.0.0.1       x.test.in
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you call the server with HTTP or HTTPS? If the "Secure" Flag is set on the cookie it can only be set after an HTTPS call

If it **was** indeed blocked by Chrome you can still see it by going into the "Network" Tab of your developer tools, select the request, click on "Cookies" and select "show filtered out request cookies". The blocked cookie should appear and you should see there why this was the case.

Comment: Yeah, it was blocked for me. But why it is working with localhost even with HTTP and secure ON?

Comment: Locally-delivered resources such as those with http://127.0.0.1 URLs, http://localhost and http://*.localhost URLs (e.g. http://dev.whatever.localhost/), and file:// URLs are also considered to have been delivered securely.
For more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395638

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in an other browser. I think chrome means, the cookie is a *fake*-secure cookie.