# This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie was blocked because it had the "Secure" attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, webforms, iis-10

I have an ASP.NET webforms/mvc hybrid app deployed on IIS 10. I have two bindings for this app one with just a localhost:portNo binding and another with DNSDomainName:portNo binding. Both are Http bindings. SSL is turned off. I get the error

"This attempt to set a cookie via a Set-Cookie was blocked because it had the "Secure" attribute but was not received over a secure connection."

when I test the DNSDomainName:portNo binding (it is failing to set sessions). The localhost:portNo binding works without any issues. Why is this happening? and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cookies are configured to require an HTTPS connection. When you try to set them on a non-secure connection, they will be rejected.

Check your `web.config` file settings for:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />
```

Change that setting to `false`, and your session cookies should start working.

**NB:** Once you publish your site, it should only ever be served over HTTPS, and this setting should be changed back to `true`.

[Secure Cookie Attribute | OWASP Foundation](https://owasp.org/www-community/controls/SecureCookieAttribute)

The `localhost` binding works because most browsers have special-case code to treat connections to that host name as "secure", even if they don't use HTTPS.

> Locally-delivered resources such as those with `http://127.0.0.1` URLs,
> `http://localhost` and  `http://*.localhost` URLs (e.g.
> `http://dev.whatever.localhost/`), and `file://` URLs are also considered
> to have been delivered securely.
> [Secure contexts - Web security | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts)

Comment: I didn't even have that in my web.config but adding it and setting it to false solved my problem. Thanks!!

Comment: where did you add the web.config file