# reactjs-axios do not send cookies in its get request

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, micro-frontend

Axios does not send cookies in get method call to back end server, i have also set the withCredential true method, but it's not working. here is the peace of my code,

```
 axios
      .get("http://192.168.0.125:3000/api/v1/profile", {
        withCredentials: true
      })
      .then((res) => console.log("res", res))
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("err", err);
        if (err.response.status === 401) navigate("/signin");
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

## Check your access control headers

You already have `withCredentials: true` so its sending cookies.

You need to have the correct access control headers on your response. this will be in your express server or wherever you're sending data to.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', hostName);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  next();
});
```

Comment: Already did it, not working. I am getting this warning in response header of request " this attempt to set a cookie via set-cookie header was blocked because it had the "secure" attribute but was not received over secure connection"

Comment: this question here might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/69395638/2504407. They says that if you don't use https your cookies will be rejected.